# Do I need to list Javascript/CSS/HTML skills on resume if frameworks/libraries are listed?

Tags: software-industry, resume, software-development, skills

If I've listed skills like Angular or other Javascript/CSS/HTML frameworks and libraries on my resume is it still necessary to specifically list HTML/CSS/Javascript as skills? I feel like one would assume the person is fairly comfortable with these if they already listed related frameworks/libraries? Just want to avoid listing the obvious and taking up lots of space but also worried that if I'm missing keywords like this on my resume then my applications are going to get filtered out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It's simply different skills.

Take me for example: I'm a backend developer and I'm pretty comfortable with Angular, it's modules and dependency injection and services and components. Ask me to center a `div` or wrap it responsively and I'm lost. Sure, I can google it and copy/paste my way around, but anybody can do that. HTML/CSS is a skill and while it does work with Angular, Angular on your CV does not imply you know it well.

That said, you need to include it anyway for people who only do tag pattern matching because they don't know any of the technologies. You don't want to be filtered out because you assumed something a dumb filter would not know.

Comment: Would you say Javascript is in the same boat as HTML/CSS in that you should explicitly list it or is it fair for recruiters to assume one is comfortable with Javascript if they have Javascript frameworks/libraries listed?

Comment: @jn025 list all languages no matter what — even industry professionals might not recognize library dependencies if they’re only vaguely familiar: you want to avoid “oh, I didn’t know React and Angular were JavaScript based” — you also run the risk of being screened by not listing.

Comment: Also, while knowing JavaScript certainly helps in identifying weird errors, Angular can be written using Typescript (or even Dart). So assuming good knowledge in JS beecause someone writes good Angular might be a stretch, too.

Answer (score 9):

I would list it, because the person doing the initial filtering may have been told: "Throw out any resume that doesn't list Javascript as a skill".

Keep in mind, the initial filtering could be done by a HR person with no technical knowledge.